# System.byte error while reading a pdf file in C#

Tags: c#

i have tried every possible solution that is given on website.

```
private byte[] GetBinaryFile()
{
    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

This is what i was trying to Read from the fileuploader which didn't work. Then i changed the idea i uploaded the file on the server first and then i was trying to read but that again gave me the same error of system.byte().  Thing is it does not return the byte format of the pdf but it worked perfectly on my local system does it has anything to do with the server? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Length isn't guaranteed to return a value. Try using FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:-

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
bytes = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```